# State not updating in a List, Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

When I try to update a list, I have 2 issues, one method (Method 1 below) only updates the data I'm passing and the rest of the data is `null` and I have the error `Null check operator used on a null value`, so my widget breaks when I listen to changes. The other method (Method 2 below) has issues because I can not specify where in the list should I update the data and I get an error `Illegal assignment to non-assignable expression. Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'. Try adding a selector.` So I'm not sure what do now, what am I missing. The code:

Method 1:

```
List<ItemData>? _items = [];

List<ItemData>? get items => _items;

//Updates only the price and the other data in the state goes null
updatePrice(ItemData price) {
    _items![_items!.indexWhere((element) => element.itemId == price.itemId)] = price;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Method 2:

```
List<ItemData>? _items = [];

List<ItemData>? get items => _items;

updatePrice(ItemData price) {
// I can't use this since I have to add an selector and I don't understand how
    _items!.firstWhere((element) => element.itemId == price.itemId) = price;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The API call:

```
 Future<ItemData> patchFee(
      currency, fee, itemId, transactionId) async {
    final response = await (ApiRequest(Method.PATCH, '/items',
        body: jsonEncode({
          "itemId": itemId,
          "transactionId": transactionId,
          "fees": [
            {
              "currency": currency,
              "type": "EXPENSE",
              "fee": fee,
              "description": "Item price",
            }
          ],
        })));
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonDecodedResponse =
        jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response!.bodyBytes));
    var list = jsonDecodedResponse['data']['fees'] as List;
    List<Fees> feesList = list.map((i) => Fees.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return ItemData(
      itemId: jsonDecodedResponse['data']['itemId'],
      transactionId: jsonDecodedResponse['data']['transactionId'],
      fees: feesList,
    );
  }
```

Action for the API call:

```
final itemStore = Provider.of<ItemStore>(context, listen: true);

...

TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
       final response = await patchFee(
      USD, 300, 123, 333);

      itemStore.updatePrice(response);
},
            child: const Text('Update Price'),
          ),
```

The patch goes through with status 200, I listen to the changes with final `itemStore = Provider.of<ItemStore>(context, listen: true);`, so I assume the error is that I'm updating the state with my `updatePrice(price)` method wrong, but can't seem to figure it out what and why.
Thanks you in advance for the help.

Comment: I will encourage you to check null value 1st. and what type of provider you are using, Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have updated the question with the correct action for the API call (patch)

Comment: Why does the list have to be nullable? `List<ItemData>? _items = [];` instead of  e.g. `final List<ItemData> _items = []; ` ? - in which case it looks to me as if your Method 1 but without the assertion operators (...`!`) works based on a quick test.

Comment: For Method2: if I understand correctly you can just use the same logic with `indexWhere` to get the index of an element with matching `itemId` and update it.
(Or is that just two versions of the same method you have tried so far?)

Comment: @AndreClements well the list can be null, that's why I putted like that.

Comment: @obywan These are two different methods and both of them are not working as intended. Through the app I have the exact same method used for a list and it works as intended, but with this module, it doesn't and I can't understand why.

Comment: should it be nullable though, rather than an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure about what you're doing, try to keep your code as simple as possible.

Playing with the `indexWhere`, `firstWhere`... methods can be tricky if you don't know what you're doing, even more with the null-safety.

If you wanna update a single item in your list, you could consider using a simple `for loop` like this :

```
void updatePrice(ItemData price) {
  //Making a shallow copy of the original list
  var datasUpdate = _items?.toList();
  
  //Since the datasUpdate is a local var
  //we can null-check it to avoid using "!" everywhere
  if (datasUpdate != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < datasUpdate.length; i++) {
      if (datasUpdate[i].id == price.id) {
        datasUpdate[i] = price;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    //Finally we update your initial List.
    //No need to use a shallow copy here
    _items = datasUpdate;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

A fully working example is available [here on this dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1e5cb2f96865be795dfbd03def15994d)

Comment: Thank you for the help but unfortunately it doesn't work for me, I get the same problem where the price is updated, but i.e. the date of it doesn't change, even though I'm not changing the data for it and it breaks because the `Null check operator used on a null value` because it makes the date null now...

Comment: With the sample above, there is nothing which is set to null. Could you provide in your question the stacktrace of your Null check operator exception ?